# dynamic cell height for custom uitableviewcell not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I created a custom tableview cell and the code is given below. I am trying to add a new UIView named **bottomTextContainer** to the **contentview** of the cell.The bottomTextContainer holds the labels of published date and source of the article. my problem is **bottomTextContainer** view is not showing inside the cell it is overlapping with the next cell.

#### ArticleCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface ArticleCell : UITableViewCell

#pragma mark- Properties

@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *source;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *publishedDate;

#pragma mark- Methods

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(nullable NSString *)reuseIdentifier;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

#### ArticleCell.m

```
#import "ArticleCell.h"

@interface ArticleCell ()

#pragma mark- Private Properties

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *bottomTextContainer;

@end

@implementation ArticleCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self createSubViews];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)createSubViews{
    
    self.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    self.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:20];
    self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    self.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    self.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:16];
    self.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    
    self.bottomTextContainer = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.bottomTextContainer];
    self.bottomTextContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    
    self.source = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [self.bottomTextContainer addSubview:self.source];
    self.source.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.source.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12];
    self.source.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    self.source.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    
    self.publishedDate = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [self.bottomTextContainer addSubview:self.publishedDate];
    self.publishedDate.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.publishedDate.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12];
    self.publishedDate.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    self.publishedDate.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    
}

- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    
    UILayoutGuide *contentViewLayout =  self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide;
    
    [self.bottomTextContainer.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.detailTextLabel.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.bottomTextContainer.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:contentViewLayout.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.bottomTextContainer.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:contentViewLayout.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
    
    [self.source.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomTextContainer.topAnchor constant:10].active = YES;
    [self.source.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomTextContainer.bottomAnchor constant:10].active = YES;
    [self.source.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomTextContainer.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.source.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomTextContainer.widthAnchor multiplier:0.5].active = YES;
    
    [self.publishedDate.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomTextContainer.topAnchor constant:10].active = YES;
    [self.publishedDate.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomTextContainer.bottomAnchor constant:10].active = YES;
    [self.publishedDate.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomTextContainer.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.publishedDate.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.source.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
}

@end
```

#### This is the result I am getting. [Show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ruh2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44;
```

Comment: I tried using that and also tried using table view delegate methods but no use